# React Router Error: useNavigation must be used within a data router

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to use `useNavigation()` from `react-router-dom`, but I get the following error:

```
Error: useNavigation must be used within a data router.
See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router.

NavBar
src/components/NavBar.js:6
  3 | import { useNavigation } from "react-router-dom";
  4 | 
  5 | function NavBar() {
> 6 |   const navigate = useNavigation();
  7 |   const handleClick = (e) => {
  8 |       navigate("/login");
  9 |   };
```

But I wrapped my whole app with `BrowserRouter` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I also use routes like below:

```
import SideMenu from "./components/SideMenu";
import Content from "./components/Content";
import Projects from "./pages/Projects";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<div>Home</div>} />
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/signin" element={<SignUp />} />
                <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
                <Route
                    path="/main"
                    element={
                        <Main
                            nav={<NavBar />}
                            sideMenu={<SideMenu />}
                            content={<Content />}
                        />
                    }
                />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And my NavBar component looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./NavBar.css";
import { useNavigation } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
    const navigate = useNavigation();
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        navigate("/login");
    };
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <ul className="nav-list">
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <button className="nav-login" onClick={handleClick}>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So in the end, my `NavBar` component is within the `BrowserRouter`, but according to the error I understand it's not the case.
Does anyone has a solution for this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `useNavigation` hook is a Data Router only hook. You are not using a Data router, but rather you are using the regular `BrowserRouter`. In other words, you are using `BrowserRouter` directly instead of one created by [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router).

[useNavigation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigation)

> This feature only works if using a data router, see [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

Since you are wanting to issue imperative navigation actions use the `useNavigate` hook instead.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate)

> The `useNavigate` hook returns a function that lets you navigate
> programmatically

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    navigate("/login");
  };

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <ul className="nav-list">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <button className="nav-login" onClick={handleClick}>
            Login
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Drew! It works, next time I go to bed early to have good rest :D

Answer (score 1):

Note well:

```
import {useNavigation, ...} from "react-router-dom;
```

will fail with this error, when you may have wanted wanted:

```
import {useNavigate, ...} from "react-router-dom;
```

Comment: Hi, while answering to already solved questions, be sure to add some value. As is, there is nothing new. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)